# Problems with Django login authentication in my code. It's always going to the else condition and outputs 'You have incorrect Username or password'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I am facing an issue with the user authentication implementation in my Django application. Even when providing the correct username and password, the system consistently displays an error message stating "You have incorrect Username or password." I have thoroughly followed the authentication procedures, ensured the correct user model.

please help me to solve this problem.

`This is view.py file`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse,redirect
from .models import registration
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("You have incorrect Username or password")

    return render(request, 'log_in.html')


def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('fullname')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('password')
        pass2 = request.POST.get('confirm_password')

        if pass1 != pass2:
            return HttpResponse("Password not matched")
        else:
            db = registration()

            db.Name = name
            db.username = username
            db.Email = email
            db.Password = pass1

            db.save()

            return redirect('log_in')


    return render(request,'sign_up.html')
```

`This is models.py for sqlite database`

```
from django.db import models

class registration(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: You need to save the password with: `make_password()`, so `db.Password = make_password(pass1)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers

Comment: I agree with @JoVi and also I like to mention that when you try to log in the user why you have written this code `login(request, check)` check instead of the user like this `login(request, user)` is it a typo or what?